# Error: no module named object_detection

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, image-recognition

I'm following [this tutorial](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10) about image recognition and i've just arrived [here](https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10#6-run-the-training). When I write that command in the cmd (I'm using Win10) it gives an error: `no module named object_detection`.
The main project folder is named obj and its path is C:\obj, I also added models and models/research/slim to the env variables but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the new repository on github about is quite different than a years ago so it's necessary to change manually all the import functions in about 20 files. This is easier than change files to other directories even though it is longer.